# how do I Import CSV file in mysql using php and codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

I am developing a website for a sales company. I want to add a bulk data of employees which will be a CSV file. I want help in doing so. A code sample will be much appreciated as I'm new in this. This code should upload the CSV first and then import it to MySQL. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Have a view with a file upload form, then have a csv_model with an upload function called by the controller. This function should contain code which looks a bit like this:

```
    if (isset($_FILES['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0 && $_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 0) {
        // Upload the file:         
        if (!is_dir($this->upload_path)) mkdir($this->upload_path,0777,TRUE);
        $config['upload_path'] = $this->upload_path;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            echo 'Error: '; print_r($error); die();
            return $error;
        }
        else
        {
        // It's uploaded, so open it, loop through it and do what you need to do
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $file_path = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
             $row = 1;
             $db_row = array();
             if (($handle = fopen($file_path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    $num = count($data);
                    $db_row[$row]['xxx'] = $data[0];
                    // Any database insertion goes here...
                }
             }

         }}
```

Comment: mate this was really helpful but it would be great if you upload a complete code. Thanks again.